# mailR: How to supress Java-Object message after sending email?

Tags: r, sendmailr

I'm using the code below to send authenticated email as documented in https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR.

Everything works but looking to suppress the Java-object message below once it's sent as it won't run via batch file.

Is this possible?

[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail@6b09bb57}"

```
send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
          to = c("recipient1@gmail.com", "Recipient 2 <recipient2@gmail.com>"),
          replyTo = c("Reply to someone else <someone.else@gmail.com>")
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "Body of the email",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "gmail_username", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wrap `send.mail(...)` in `invisible()`?

Comment: That worked like a charm!! THANK YOU!! A+++++

Answer (score 0):

Thanks LukaA!!

Wrap send.mail(...) in invisible() did the trick!!